# LogLinearPlot problem with plotrange

Tags: logarithmic-scale

i have this equation

```
y= (5.41*10^-15 E^(-148/T))/T^(3/2) + (
 2.00122*10^-10 E^(-((
   53.124 (1 + (59.357 T - 1.0404 T^2 + 0.0091653 T^3)/(
  1000 + 201.65 T + 2.7621 T^2 + 0.00098305 T^3))^(1/3))/T^(
   1/3))))/(
  T^(2/3) (1 + (59.357 T - 1.0404 T^2 + 0.0091653 T^3)/(
   1000 + 201.65 T + 2.7621 T^2 + 0.00098305 T^3))^(5/6))
```

I can plot it easily with the Plot command

```
 Plot[y, {T, 10, 1000}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{10, 1000}, {10^-20, 5 10^-16}}]
```

but i would like the x frame to be in logarithmic form, so i used  [`LogLinearPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogLinearPlot.html)

however, it shows the wrong plot and it does not apply on my desired range.

```
  LogLinearPlot[y, {T, 10, 1000}, Frame -> True]
```

or

```
  LogLinearPlot[y, {T, 10, 1000}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> 
  {10^-20, 10^-16}]
```

the correct figure is figure 2.

what is the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

your code is right.

```
LogLinearPlot[y, {T, 10, 1000}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 4*^-16}}]
```

and

```
Plot[y, {T, 10, 1000}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 4*^-16}}]
```

both give out the right graph.

you can notice that the peak of function is at the same position.

Comment: thanks for your response. but the first command gives very small cure @wuyudi i edited the question with a picture